# Выделяется ли запятыми "вообще-то"?

Tags: вводные-слова, пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Помогите двум технарям решить спор по русскому языку. На кону два литра красной икры и коньяк.
Суть в следующем. Есть предложение, в котором используется слово "вообще-то". Мы, конечно, просмотрели много правил, но к единому мнению не пришли. Решили вас подключить как арбитров нашего спора. Теперь от вас завит то, кто получит коньяк, а кто красную икру.
Итак.
Спорщик А утверждает, что в следующем предложении, слово "вообще-то" не требует выделения запятыми и следует писать так:
"Я вообще-то не люблю купаться".
Спорщик Б утверждает, что слово "вообще-то" является вводным словом, его нужно выделить запятыми и писать нужно так:
"Я, вообще-то, не люблю купаться".
Рассудите, кто из спорщиков прав? Возможны еще два варианта: оба правы и писать можно и так, и так, или оба неправы, нельзя писать ни так, ни так. Но мы эти варианты не рассматривали.

С уважением ))

Comment: @Fred, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Возможны два варианта (и с запятыми, и без).

*Я вообще-то не люблю купаться* (= на самом деле, обычно).

*Я, вообще-то, не люблю купаться* (= к вашему сведению).

ВООБЩЕ-ТО бывает:

1.Вводным словом (но очень редко): выражает субъективное отношение к факту (= к вашему сведению), выделяется интонационно.

*«Здесь, вообще-то, время зря не теряют», - подумал Семка* (В.Шукшин).

*Он, вообще-то, всегда отдает* (В.Шукшин).

2.Невводным: употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия (= обычно, в большей части случаев, на самом деле).

*Вообще-то Чик терпеть не мог, когда его кто-нибудь целовал* (Иск).

3.Частицей: невозможно поставить логическое ударение на частицу *вообще-то*, интонационно не выделяется.

*Вообще-то я пишу не для славистов* (С. Довлатов).

*Ты-то человек грамотный, а я вообще-то буквы понимаю, а пишу плохо* (В.Войнович).

Comment: "Мы, конечно, просмотрели много правил, но к единому мнению не пришли", - написал нам  Фред. Теперь у него появилась возможность ознакомиться еще с тремя правилами - интересно, это и есть весь итог?

Comment: "Возможны 2 варианта".  
Как автор произнесет, так и напишет. Его выбор.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: Я, вообще-то, не люблю купаться".

В данном предложении это вводное слово со значением "вообще говоря" (вводное слово относится ко всему сообщению и служит для его оценки). В состав предложения вводное слово н входит и произносится с особой интонацией исключения (паузы, измененный темп речи).

Сочетание "вообще-то" может быть частицей, если в предложении есть сопоставление: Я вообще-то не люблю купаться, но сейчас очень жарко (сделаю исключение).

В этом случае частица является необходимым структурным элементом для выражения сопоставительных отношений (ВООБЩЕ-ТО...НО), входит в состав предложения и не обособляется.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Можно ли отличить друг от друга следующие слова, которые используются для проверки вводного слова "вообще-то": обычно, в большей части случаев, на самом деле? Можно ли догадаться, для чего они говорятся - для нашего сведения или еще зачем?  Как в этом случае отличить частицу от наречия, можно ли их вообще различить? Вот уж поистине – всё от лукавого. Поэтому давайте очистим сознание и на время забудем обо всех правилах.

Перед нами слова:  ВООБЩЕ, ВООБЩЕ-ТО, ВООБЩЕ ГОВОРЯ, и у них один корень, который наводит нас на мысль о каком-то обобщении. Вы можете обособить эти слова и назвать их вводными, а можете не обособлять, считая частицей (наречием). Решим нашу задачу для конкретных примеров:

1) Поплывем  на ту сторону? – Нет, я не люблю плавать. – Не бойся, здесь неглубоко. – Да я вообще не люблю плавать.

2) Поплывем  на ту сторону? – Я, вообще-то (вообще говоря),  не люблю плавать. – Не бойся, здесь неглубоко. –  Ладно, поплыли.

3) Поплывем  на ту сторону? – Я вообще-то не люблю плавать, но ладно, поплыли.

Таким образом, исходя из разных ситуаций, мы определяем, когда обобщение относится к слову(1), когда оно обобщает ситуацию (2) и когда используется при сопоставлении в качестве части союза. (3). У нас есть разная семантика, разная грамматика и разная интонация. Если у нас всё это есть, то правила не нужны. А если и нужны, то только для того, чтобы объяснить другим уже принятое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню Розенталем коротко.

"Слово ВООБЩЕ является вводным, если оно употреблено в значении "вообще говоря".
В других значениях слово ВООБЩЕ вводным не является..."

Так что у Софии всё подробно разъяснено. Икрой и коньяком следует поделиться с ней. ;)))